# ParsleyJS custom validator always fails the validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

https://codepen.io/joshuajazleung/pen/jGEyNa

```
<form data-parsley-validate>
  <input type="file" name="files" multiple data-parsley-max-files="4">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

window.Parsley
  .addValidator('maxFiles', {
    requirementType: 'integer',
    validateNumber: function(value, requirement) {
      return true;
    },
    messages: {
      en: 'Maximum number of files is 4.',
    }
  });
```

The file input is supposed to be invalid all the time because the validator return true (for testing purposes). But when I clicked submit button, the input isn't valid. I am wondering why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the value of you input is not a valid number (ever) and you only defined `validateNumber`. You need to define a `validateString`.

To validate files, inspire yourself from the [custom validators example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/customvalidator.html)